# vb.NET Database application fails to connect server PC (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have made one vb.NET database application in MS Visual Studio 2019 using MySQL Datatbase. My Application is running fine without any error message in Development PC (which is standalone).

**My Target is:**
Server PC and User PC will be different (Both will be connected through Centralized LAN Network). I want to move to another PC for as Server and as User.

**Problem:**
When i am doing so there is an error message “Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts” in user PC. Here Ping is okay between server PC to User-PC. Firewall of Server PC is Disabled but in User-PC it is Enabled.

**What i have did:**
In new server PC i have installed MySQL software (as server mode), and successfully imported the database through command line. Since my Development PC is standalone so used Pen Drive for carrying the database .sql file.
I have copied debug folder from my application and run into on user-PC. Then error message comes. (“Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts). In user-PC i did not install any packages of MySQL.

In my Development PC following setting i have done.

MySQL Workbench Connection Settings

1. Connection Name: CONELD01
2. Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
3. Username: root
4. Password: htcc.123
5. Hostname: 127.0.0.1
6. Port: 3306

Here I have made 3 Database

1. Database Name: db_wo
2. Database Name: db_die
3. Database Name: db_ac

vb.NET Application Database connection settings:

4. Server: 127.0.0.1
5. Username: root
6. Password: htcc.123
7. Database Name: db_wo, db_die, db_ac

Connection String in my vb.NET Application Setting are as:

12. `server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=htcc.123;database=db_wo`
13. `server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=htcc.123;database=db_die`
14. `server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=htcc.123;database=db_ac`

**What i Have Tried:**
In my Server-PC when i copied and run the debug folder into it, Application running fine. but when i trying for access the server-PC database from remote PC (User-PC) error message comes as mentioned above.

After this error i went back to my Development PC and made small changes in Connection String in my Application settings as below, i,e i have put the server-PC IP into connection string. (Server-PC IP is 10.68.20.30)

1. `server=10.68.20.30;user id=root;password=htcc.123;database=db_wo`
2. `server=10.68.20.30;user id=root;password=htcc.123;database=db_die`
3. `server=10.68.20.30;user id=root;password=htcc.123;database=db_ac`

After changes made debug and run. Then Copied this and run into User-PC, but this time different error message came. Error Message: “Host ‘User-PC’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server”. Same error coming when i run that dedug folder into Server-PC. But previously when debug folder was not changed it was running fine.

If i am missing any information in order to solve it please let me know, i will give full information regarding this. However i am attaching a file where figure representation will be there.

Barun

[image]

Comment: You really should enable the firewall on the server - you wouldn't want it getting infected with malware and destroying all your hard work. [MySQL Guide to Ports](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-guide-to-ports/).

Answer (score 0):

On the Server check the my.ini for the addresses/interfaces the server is listening to. Maybe your MySQL ist only listening on ::1